What is the most efficient way to update a large list of objects using Spring and Hibernate?
I’m starting a small project using Java Spring Boot and Hibernate. It’s a simple game app involving a deck of cards. A deck can contain anywhere from a few hundred to a thousand cards. Each card is a straightforward entity with the following properties: id, question, answer, details, creationDate, authorId, and categoryId.
To create a deck, the player begins by selecting the categories of cards they want to play with. Based on these categories, I retrieve the corresponding list of cardIds. Using this list, I build the deck by fetching all the necessary card information and adding a new property, hasBeenRead, to each card. The deck is then persisted in the database.
When a card is drawn, its hasBeenRead property is updated to true, ensuring it cannot be drawn again.
I am not very experienced with Hibernate, but I suspect that updating the entire deck object every time a card’s hasBeenRead property changes may not be the most efficient approach.
Would you recommend a different strategy to improve performance?

Why not load the whole deck into the memory? I think the state of cards in the deck should be exclusive to the game session, which mean it doesn't need to be persisted into a database.

If you can number your sessions consequently you can store lastSessionRead instead of  hasBeenRead. If number in lastSessionRead less than current, then card wasn't drawn in this session.

Interesting. I’m not entirely sure when lastSessionRead should be stored. But and I’m not yet very familiar with the concept of 'sessions' either.

It should be updated same time you currently set hasBeenRead to true. Session is just a counter you increment each time you want to set all hasBeenRead to false. You need to store it in DB. It called session because it represent game session.
